# Use case chart: How to use <<include>> but just for some role?

Tags: use-case

In the following image there is a part of a use diagram I draw.

- both Administrator and Professor roles can access to cases beginning with "View" but **only the Administrator** can access cases beggining with "Delete".

How could i specify this?

[image]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use if condition(diamond block) in between **<>** for delete use case so that you can separate the access of administrator and professor. or if you want, you can add text but that make a negative impact on your UML diagram.